# How to access a string value of a shared preference from a method of another class

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

The title is the question. I have saved a string value in the shared preference and i was able to access it in that class. Now i want to access it from a another method of another class. Tried some ways but didn't work.

The class that saves string inside shared preference:

http://pastie.org/4254511

Class trying to retrieve the username that was previously save in shared preference:

```
public class testSharedPrefernce extends Activity{
TextView tv;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.lo);
     tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
     String name = myPrefs.getString("NAME", "YourName");
     tv.setText(name);
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just make a constructor of that class which accepts the context.As example:

```
class Abc
{
    Context contaxt;
    public Abc(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
..........
..........
// now use this context to SharedPref..
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for get preferences.

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
boolean cbvalue = myPrefs.getBoolean("CHECKBOX", false);
String name = myPrefs.getString("NAME", "YourName");
String paswrd =myPrefs.getString("PASSWORD", "123");
```

Use below code for save preferences.

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();

prefsEditor.putString("NAME", "Dipak");
prefsEditor.putString("PASSWORD", "Dipak123");
prefsEditor.commit();
```

Comment: Don't i have to give the name of the class somewhere to which the saved preference belongs to?

Comment: @Sindu_ no it is not required here.

Comment: Used this code and i tried to display the string inside name in a textView but the string "Your name" gets displayed not the value inside the shared preference Name

Comment: @Sindu_ put both class in your question so i will give you exact solution.

Comment: The Login class code is long so i have given the link.I was able to successfully save the username to shared preference in the Login class. I want to now retrieve the username in the testSharedPrefernce class

Comment: String name = myPrefs.getString("NAME", "YourName"); this makes "Your name" to be taken when trying to retrieve the value in the NAME.

Comment: @Sindu_ this code is working in my application, you first create one demo and then try it.